What is the jurisdiction of the proposed bill SB-1047 in California?
The latest proposed version of "SB-1047 Safe and Secure Innovation for Frontier Artificial Intelligence Models Act" can be found here. Since it regulates a service (artificial intelligence models) rather than physical products, its hard to figure out what its jurisdiction is supposed to be. Does it cover only AI models built in California? Only models sold in California? Every model in the world?
The law is mute on jurisdictional limits but presumably some must exist, as California has ~zero power to impose anything outside its own borders.

The idea that a state/country cannot impose anything outside its own borders is a (somewhat commonly held) myth. Legislatures absolutely can, and do, pass extraterritorial laws.

It doesn't regulate a service. It defines certain requirements for developers and providers of certain computational capabilities:

22603 (a) Before beginning to initially train a covered model, the developer shall do all of the following: ...
22604 (a) A person that operates a computing cluster shall implement written policies and procedures to do all of the following when a customer utilizes compute resources that would be sufficient to train a covered model: ...

And imposes civil penalties for violations:

22606 (a) The Attorney General may bring a civil action for a violation of this chapter and to recover all of the following: ...

See this answer that explains how, unless explicitly said otherwise, the jurisdiction is assumed to be territorial. I.e.: individuals and companies in California are to be covered by the law.

OK so if a company releases a model in Arizona... when would the law apply to them? When they sell it to someone in California? Or it wouldn't apply to them at all?

@JonathanReez it doesn't matter where the company releases anything. The law talks about training a model, and operating a computer cluster (and both terms defined in the law), and requirements for developers and operators.

@JonathanReez Think of it as analogous to a factory that makes a product (the trained AI). It doesn't matter where you sell the products, only where the factory is.


The law is mute on jurisdictional limits but presumably some must exist, as California has ~zero power to impose anything outside its own borders.

That sounds like a non-sequitur to me, it makes very little sense to limit the scope of a law based on that. If anything, it seems existing statutes (not only in the US) do the exact opposite and either

Claim very broad application (e.g. universal jurisdiction, jurisdiction based on the location or citizenship of a consumer or victim)
Deliberately limit their scope where to avoid conflicts of norms or serve various interests (e.g. anti-bribery rules that explicitly do not apply to foreign operations of local businesses)

The former is useful to affirm a principle or make a political or diplomatic point even if it has limited practical impact. The latter is useful to constrain law enforcement and the justice system, precisely because enforcement would be possible without this limitation. By contrast, you don't need to spell out what is or is not materially impossible in law, that's not what norms are for.
In a comment, you mention an hypothetical model “released in Arizona” but it's not directly relevant to SB-1047 and somewhat unclear what it would mean in practice. You seem to be wishing for some definition that could be exploited to create a loophole but it's hard to see why that would be good for California. From the perspective of the drafters of the law, it's much better to create some uncertainty to nudge as many businesses as possible to focus on implementing the law instead of circumventing it.
In practice, just as US financial sanctions are pretty hard to ignore, it will be difficult to run a (tech) business with zero connection to California, be it the infrastructure used, employees or business locations, or customers, especially if you consider the thresholds to trigger the rule (only very costly models are covered, which imply vast ressources and large investments that are hard to imagine without Silicon Valley VC-money and customers). So if it chooses to leverage any of these to pressure businesses, California definitely has a lot of power to influence what's being done beyond its borders.

Hm but then… could North Dakota pass the same bill and claim global jurisdiction?

@JonathanReez They could always try, who is to say they cannot? Of course, the jurisdiction is not really global in this case and there will also be a lot of pragmatic decisions on what you want to enforce but why bind your hands behind your back before you even know what the most problematic issues are going to be? You seem to be looking at it from the perspective of the model developer who hopes to find an easy out to claim a model is out of reach on a technicality but this really doesn't make sense for anybody else.

On many issues, you want to have some way to police stuff that impacts consumer in the state, which indeed means that a given product / business could fall within the scope of dozens of different regulations. That's basically what's behind the large multistate litigation you see in the US.

Then what you see is that some entities (California in the US, the US and EU globally) emerge as powerful sources of regulation because they have more resources to create and enforce new rules and businesses cannot ignore them. Other entities typically try to align with one of them, to piggyback on their work, facilitate trade, and benefit from their enforcement efforts.

California is in particularly strong position to do it on tech / digital products (data protection, AI models) because it's very difficult to imagine you could completely ignore it in the creation and distribution of these products. And to be honest, the tech industry tends to complain loudly every time but they mostly get their way in the end. SB-1047 already had a very limited scope (very expensive models) and is still getting weakened. It serves them well to have a tech-friendly state set the mood and preempt other, potentially more demanding regulation, from other places.

One last thing is that you want to keep legislation as simple as possible. The state attorney or some state agency can always decide what's worth pursuing  but why create an extra opportunity to argue about what “releasing” in this or that state mean? The underlying assumption is that it's good for the public for models to have specific features (say a kill switch) and if that means some AI business in Australia decides to build one just in case they might want to expand to the US and deploy their model on a cluster that's partly in California then that's just a beneficial side-effect.
